# How to print text from PL SQL using Visual Studio

Tags: oracle, visual-studio, plsql

I am using Visual Studio for PL/SQL. It does not let me print. How can I print any text and test my methods? It just  says "PL/SQL procedure successfully completed".

for this block  It just  says "PL/SQL procedure successfully completed".

```
begin
dbms_output.put_line('Hello');
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Client-side software usually use `DBMS_OUTPUT.GET_LINE` to get lines previously put via `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE` by user's script.  You can do the same way.

Comment: @BurakCanlı - Show your code.

Comment: Here is my code
begin
dbms_output.put_line('Hello');
end;
 It just says "PL/SQL procedure successfully completed".

Comment: @BurakCanlı - Where is your invocation of `GET_LINE` which didn't work?